# Regex for Spintax

Tags: regex

I have a little problem with a spintax. I have text in this way:

```
Hi {man|buddy|mate} how is going ? You {cool|ok} ?
```

I just want a regex to make a random sentence like

```
Hi buddy how is going ? You cool ?
```

Would be much appreciated.

Comment: You've asked 10 questions and you haven't accepted any of them.  Please go back and accept some of your older questions if the answer was useful to you.

Comment: What programming language are you wanting to use for this?

Answer (score 2):

regex can't do this, you can match `{man|buddy|mate}` and split but random select one you must do without regex

regex for matching various words:

```
(?<={)((.+?\|)+?.+?)(?=})
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer ... but if I have 100 words for spinning, how to tell him go on the next one ?

Comment: split by |, or use regex **[^|]+**, and select random one